# Visual Studio stuck while debugging Xamarin app on device

Tags: android, visual-studio, debugging, xamarin

I tried to debug on Honor 5x KIW-L22 device today following the steps to [Set Up Device for Development](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/set_up_device_for_development/).

When I press F5 in VS, it stops midway and my device asks to install the app, which I accept. After installation is finished, I can run the app on the device, but it seems like it's not stopping at any error. It does not seem like VS is in debug mode; it seems like it's still stuck in installation mode.

When I tried to cancel the build, VS showed `2>Waiting for the currently executing task "InstallPackageAssemblies" to cancel.`

1. How do I fix this?
2. In the setup guide under [Installing Unverified Drivers in Windows 8](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/set_up_device_for_development/#Installing_Unverified_Drivers_in_Windows_8), it asked to "Access the Windows 8 Advanced Boot Options", but once I'm in the advanced boot options, which option do I choose? Which option do I restart Windows into? I'm using Win10 Pro.

Comment: For 2, I think just rebooting from the command line with `shutdown.exe /r /o` should be all you need to do to install the Unverified driver for your device. Once installed, just reboot as you normally would.

Comment: Not debug your app, just run your app using "start without debugging", how about the result? Do you get nay output messages in the output or Error list window during debugging or compiled time?